# "No Installation Candidate" when trying to install build-essential

Tags: apt

`apt-get install build-essential` fails with the following errors:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

I had just run `sudo apt-get update` before trying this install.

The folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty. Here's the meat of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
$ grep deb\ http: /etc/apt/sources.list  #(with "deb http://" deleted)  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse  
us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted  
security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe  
security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse  
extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

This with ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

```
apt-cache policy build-essential 
build-essential:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: (none)
 Version table:
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you include the output of `apt-cache policy build-essential` in your question? Also include the output of `grep -r ^deb\  /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list` to list all your sources..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved.  In Ubuntu Software Center >> Edit >> Software Sources, I changed the server to Main Server and then run `sudo apt-get update`.  Then `sudo apt-get install build-essential`  which worked.

Answer (score 1):

## With Command Line

If you want to solve this annoying problem using the command line. You should edit the file `/etc/apt/source.list`.

Add the line `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main`. 
Replacing `cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`  with the [mirror](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/build-essential/download) in question, depending on your geographical position, if your distribution is bionic. If not, put in the right one.

Answer (score 0):

## This worked for me

1. Run `sudo software-properties-gtk`
2. Under 'Ubuntu Software' tab select/tick the first 4 options- main, universe, restricted, multiverse

[image: Softwares & Updates]

3. Click 'Close'
4. Click 'Reload'

Now, try your install command again.