# “No Installation Candidate” when trying to install gcc

Tags: software-installation

I am doing these via terminal. I am trying to install GCC package on ubuntu-14.04.2-server-i386

I encounter this [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316102/no-installation-candidate-when-trying-to-install-build-essential) which is similar in nature except my problem is trying to install gcc instead of build essentials.

It appears the solution is to install software-center however i encountered the same problem when I am trying to install software-center.

[image]

How do i solve this problem ???

I need to find a way to install software-center and then change the server to Main Server via terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install software-center, you need to change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include 
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted`
Since this is a server installation you can use the editor of your choice. Nano should be installed allready. So:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the line

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
```

and run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: How do i add "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main" to /etc/apt/sources

Comment: can you post the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: No such file or directory when i tried cat /etc/apt/sources , my current directory is root

Comment: I had forgotten the .list, so what I meant was cat /etc/apt/sources.list. I have modified my answer.

Comment: I was able to add it but still unable to find packages

Comment: maybe you need to add deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted